# Como fazer um INNER JOIN com duas tabelas em Bancos diferentes?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Tenho dois bancos diferentes que faço a conexão da seguinte forma:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
abstract class BancoDados
{
const host = 'localhost';
const novoweb = 'novoweb';
const WebAccount = 'Web_Account';
const Member = 'Member';
const user = 'usuario';
const password = 'senha';
static function conectarW()
{
    try 
    {
        $pdoW = new PDO("mysql:host=".self::host.";dbname=".self::novoweb.";charset=utf8", self::user, self::password);
        $pdoW->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $pdoW;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
static function conectarWA()
{
    try 
    {
        $pdoWA = new PDO("mysql:host=".self::host.";dbname=".self::WebAccount.";charset=utf8", self::user, self::password);
        $pdoWA->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $pdoWA;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
}
```

Tenho dois valores no banco `novoweb` na tabela `shopweb` com as colunas `id` e `nome`, onde o `id` eu insiro no banco `Web_Account` na tabela GameTail na coluna `ItemIdx` porem não sei como fazer o `INNER JOIN` pois realizo a consulta assim.

```
static function historicoshopweb($pdoWA,$id,$admin)
{
    try {
        if ($admin == 1) {
            $historico = $pdoWA->prepare("SELECT * FROM GameTail  ORDER BY RegDate DESC");
            $historico->execute();
        } else {
            $historico = $pdoWA->prepare("SELECT * FROM GameTail WHERE IdIdx = :id ORDER BY RegDate DESC");
            $historico->bindValue(":id",$id);
            $historico->execute();
        }
            $historicos = $historico->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            return $historicos;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Então quero no lugar de aparecer o `ItemIdx` aparecer o nome do item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo o que percebi, ambos os bancos estão no mesmo server e são acessados pelos mesmo usuário. Sendo assim, tente fazer a conexão sem passar o nome do banco de dados e faça o join assim:

```
SELECT g1.*, g2.* FROM WebAccount.GameTail g1 left join novoweb.GameTail g2 on g2.IdIdx = g1.IdIdx ORDER BY g1.RegDate DESC
```

Comment: utilizo o $pdoW ou o $pdoWA? não ficou claro isso para mim.

Comment: Tente fazer uma conexão sem passar o "dbname", desta forma: `$pdoW = new PDO("mysql:host=".self::host.";charset=utf8", self::user, self::password);`